# Winrs works while pywinrm module returns "the specified credentials were rejected by the server" error

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, winrm, winrs

I have a setup where I can winrs to the remote machine successfully without issues. However when I use pywinrm, I get an error about credentials.

Here is the authentication details of the remote windows the machine.
How one would go debugging this issue?

```
winrm get winrm/config/service/auth
Auth
    Basic = false [Source="GPO"]
    Kerberos = true [Source="GPO"]
    Negotiate = false [Source="GPO"]
    Certificate = false
    CredSSP = false [Source="GPO"]
    CbtHardeningLevel = Strict [Source="GPO"]
```

I tried this both from windows and linux and I get the same result. From the windows machine I can do winrs without issues.

Windows output:

```
import winrm
sess = winrm.Session('<hostname>', auth=('MOzsoy', '***'), transport='kerberos')
sess.run_cmd('hostname')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mozsoy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 328, in _send_message_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\mozsoy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error:  for url: http://<hostname>:5985/wsman

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mozsoy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\winrm\__init__.py", line 40, in run_cmd
    shell_id = self.protocol.open_shell()
  File "C:\Users\mozsoy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\winrm\protocol.py", line 166, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
  File "C:\Users\mozsoy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\winrm\protocol.py", line 243, in send_message
    resp = self.transport.send_message(message)
  File "C:\Users\mozsoy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 322, in send_message
    response = self._send_message_request(prepared_request, message)
  File "C:\Users\mozsoy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 332, in _send_message_request
    raise InvalidCredentialsError("the specified credentials were rejected by the server")
winrm.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError: the specified credentials were rejected by the server
```

Linux output:

```
import winrm
sess = winrm.Session('<hostname>', auth=('MOzsoy', '***'), transport='kerberos')
sess.run_cmd("hostname")
/home/mozsoy/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/vendor/requests_kerberos/kerberos_.py:176: NoCertificateRetrievedWarning: Requests is running with a non urllib3 backend, cannot retrieve server certificate for CBT
  NoCertificateRetrievedWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mozsoy/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 328, in _send_message_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 840, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error:  for url: http://<hostname>:5985/wsman

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mozsoy/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/__init__.py", line 40, in run_cmd
    shell_id = self.protocol.open_shell()
  File "/home/mozsoy/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 166, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
  File "/home/mozsoy/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 243, in send_message
    resp = self.transport.send_message(message)
  File "/home/mozsoy/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 309, in send_message
    self.build_session()
  File "/home/mozsoy/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 292, in build_session
    self.setup_encryption()
  File "/home/mozsoy/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 298, in setup_encryption
    self._send_message_request(prepared_request, '')
  File "/home/mozsoy/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 332, in _send_message_request
    raise InvalidCredentialsError("the specified credentials were rejected by the server")
winrm.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError: the specified credentials were rejected by the server
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that pywinrm doesn't like this setting:
CbtHardeningLevel = Strict [Source="GPO"]

As it is configured through GPO, you probably need to contact your admin about this.

From what I found so far, pywinrm can't handle "Strict", but you need to use "Relaxed"

I encounterd this for Ansible, but I guess it's due to pywinrm.

https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/issues/109

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html#http-401-credentials-rejected